# SQL: filter "after" aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a set of normalized tables with one-to-many and many-to-many relationships.

For most queries I am really interested in a highly denormalized view which shows:

1. Entity-per-row for one specific table
2. Aggregated information about related entities from other tables

Here is a [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dTQWiqVD9xRxPov4v6Qxom/2), or consider the following DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people(
    name TEXT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE fruit(
    name TEXT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE likes(
    person TEXT REFERENCES people (name),
    fruit TEXT REFERENCES fruit (name),
    PRIMARY KEY (person, fruit)
);

INSERT INTO people VALUES ('Joe'), ('Brandon'), ('Miranda');

INSERT INTO fruit VALUES ('Banana'), ('Apple'), ('Orange'), ('Strawberry');

INSERT INTO likes VALUES ('Joe', 'Banana'), ('Joe', 'Apple'), ('Joe', 'Orange');
INSERT INTO likes VALUES ('Brandon', 'Apple');
INSERT INTO likes VALUES ('Miranda', 'Apple'), ('Miranda', 'Banana'), ('Miranda', 'Orange'), ('Miranda', 'Strawberry');
```

I want to show my users a filtered list of who likes which fruit so I construct the following query:

```sql
SELECT person, string_agg(DISTINCT fruit, ', ' ORDER BY fruit) AS fruit
FROM likes
GROUP BY person;
```

This shows me a table with each person's name and a list of fruit they like. So far, so good. But now if I filter the list:

```sql
SELECT person, string_agg(DISTINCT fruit, ', ' ORDER BY fruit) AS fruit
FROM likes
WHERE fruit='Orange'
GROUP BY person;
```

I get a list of people who like oranges, without the information about what *other* fruit those same people like.

Now, I understand why this happens: `WHERE` takes precedence over `SELECT`. What I would like to know is, is there a better way? How can I subset by `fruit='Orange'`, but still get a list of all fruit that a person likes in one row?

Do I *have* to use a CTE or an `INTERSECT`? The below gets me what I want, but I am afraid that it can get costly with multiple tables and multiple joins in each subquery because my real problem is obviously much larger, and with more tables like that:

```
WITH select_people AS (
    SELECT person
    FROM likes
    WHERE fruit = 'Orange'
)
SELECT person, string_agg(DISTINCT fruit, ', ' ORDER BY fruit) AS fruit
FROM likes
WHERE person in (select person from select_people)
GROUP BY person;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if this would work, but maybe try using a HAVING clause after the GROUP BY and retain only groups where orange is in the list of fruits that the person likes.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter on the results of aggregates by using HAVING, or by wrapping the query into a subquery and then using WHERE in the outer query.  The problem with HAVING is that you can't refer to the aggregate by alias, so you have to repeat the expression, which is ugly and fragile as they can get out of sync, so I would usually use the 2nd method instead.  But I changed your string_agg to an array_agg, as there is no clean way to do the contains expression `@>` on the string_agg.

```
select * from (
  SELECT person, array_agg(DISTINCT fruit ORDER BY fruit) AS fruit
  FROM likes
  GROUP BY person
) foo
WHERE fruit @> ARRAY['Orange']
```

If few people like Orange and you have the right indexes, then the self-join method already given should be faster than this, but I think this method is more flexible and easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you, that looks clean. I have two questions though: could you explain how `HAVING` could be used in this case? And I appreciate the `array_agg` method, but wouldn't `LIKE` with wildcards be an equivalent of this for the `string_agg`? Or is that much slower / bad for some other reason?

Comment: @ennui the problem with using LIKE in a string_agg is to make sure the LIKE returns exactly what you want.  For example, '%Orange%' will match 'Orange Carrots', while '%,Orange,%' will not match 'Orange' occurring at the beginning or end of the aggregated string.

Answer (score 1):

You could self join `likes` with an `inner join` to limit this to people that have `Orange` records:

```
SELECT likes.person, string_agg(DISTINCT likes.fruit, ', ' ORDER BY likes.fruit) AS fruit
FROM likes
inner join likes orange_filter
  on likes.person = orange_filter.person
  and orange_filter.fruit = 'Orange'
GROUP BY likes.person;
```

[Fiddle Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e1c95/4)